# How to create a toggle dropdown menu without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am avoiding jquery for most of my practices so I can familiarize myself with javascript but I am having a bit of trouble trying to get sub menus to toggle properly with transitions.
Example of my [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renren89/10j79rrf/2/) My original code:

```
var submenu = document.getElementById('sub-menu');
function toggleMenu() {
  if (submenu.style.display == "none") {
    submenu.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    submenu.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

works but it's inefficiency makes it unusable nor it's re-usability as it only works per menu and has to be reassigned id/class for the next.

My next idea was to user an event handler for clicks when the `item-has-children` is clicked but I am unsure on how to target the sub-menu of the clicked Menu.

Any advice or redirection would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is MUCH more to JavaScript than simple DOM manipulation.  If you really want to learn, my advice is use jQuery.  It's only 96 Kb (nothing at today's internet speeds), very likely cached in the browser already anyway, and MORE than proven.  It'll get the tactical details out of the way, at let you move on to building something that matters.  If you try to re-invent the wheel, you'll find over time that you're building your own version of jQuery, only less performant and with more bugs.

Comment: This one will help you out: http://codepen.io/pedronauck/pen/fcaDw

Comment: If OP doesn't want to use jQuery, he/she may have reasons (good or bad) not to use it, so why force OP into it? And why jQuery in particular and not another? You'll get people that will say that using jQuery is crazy because xyz is better than jQuery (replace xyz by d3.js, AngularJS, Dojo, Kendo UI, MooTools, or whatever poison you want to pick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I based my answer on the code on JSFiddle. It is different from the code in the question, but both contains some JavaScript and CSS errors. For example:

- `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array, but you try to use it as it returns an object.
- As you apply the toggle to the outer `li`, it affects even when you click on the inner list (although this may be by design, it would be better on the `a`).
- The CSS for the selected submenu should be `.sub-menu.selected`, instead of `.sub-menu .selected` (with a space).
- `display` transitions are not supported (at least not yet afaik).

I have modified those things, and here is a sample plain JavaScript code of what you want:

```js
// get the array with all the links and traverse it binding the click event
var allHasChildren = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children a");
for (var x = 0; x < allHasChildren.length; x++) {
    allHasChildren[x].onclick = function() {
        // get the first submenu and toggle using classes
        var subMenu = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[0];
        if (subMenu.classList.contains('selected')) {
            subMenu.classList.remove("selected");
        } else {
            subMenu.classList.add("selected");
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
.sub-menu.selected {
    display: block;
    transition: transform .2s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item One</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Five</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Six</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-has-children">
        <a href="#0">Main Item Two</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Five</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Sub Item Six</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can also see it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/10j79rrf/5/

As you can see, you can achieve what you want just using plain JavaScript, but as noted by other users, it will look uglier and take more lines of code than using a library to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. It was exactly what I was looking for and now I can study the code to get an understanding of it.  The reason I picked to stick w/ javascript is it seems a like more compatible when it comes to transitioning between different framework and offerings so as I am learning I am getting more mileage out of it.

Answer (score -3):

You can make you jQuery function re-usable, by making the selectors as general as possible. A two leveled menu has  `<li>` with `<ul>` inside it. We can use that to our advantage by using the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) selector:

```
$('li:has(ul)').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Also see this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/10j79rrf/3/).

This script is small and usable on other of your sites as well.

Comment: OP specifically said they are avoiding jQuery.